# A Sparse graph with sparse subgraphs

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I've encountered this problem during research regarding Auction Theory, but it's a pure combinatorial problem that can be stated in the language of graphs and matrices:

Is there, for every $d>0$, a $d$-regular graph $G=(V,E)$, with $\vert V \vert = d^2$ (and hence $\vert E \vert = \frac{1}{2}d^3$), such that for every vertex set $S \subseteq V$ with $\vert S \vert = d+1$, the induced sub-graph $G \vert_S$ contains $O(d)$ edges?

In the language of matrices:
define the restriction of a matrix $A \in M_{n \times n}$ to a set $S \subseteq \{ 1,...,n\}$ (given the natural monotone enumeration $\pi_S: \{ 1,...,\vert S \vert\} \rightarrow S$), to be a matrix $A \vert_S \in M_{\vert S \vert \times \vert S \vert}$ with entries:

${A \vert _S}_{ij} = A_{\pi(i)\pi(j)}$

Conversely,$A \vert_S$ can be thought of as the matrix A after we've deleted all it's rows and columns which aren't in S.

The question becomes:
Is there, for every $d>0$ a symmetric binary matrix $A \in M_{d^2 \times d^2 (\{ 0,1\})}$ with exactly $d$ 1s in each row and each column, and a main diagonal of zeroes, for which the restriction $A \vert_S$ contains $O(d)$ 1s for every $S \subseteq {1,...,d^2}$ with $\vert S \vert = d+1$?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! Nice question. I would first try to address this if $d$ is a power of 2.

Comment: As for me, your question is not trivial. I tried to prove and to disprove the existence of such a family of graphs (I even tried to use the probabilistic method to construct modified Cayley graphs) and to find info about it in Internet, but all this gave no advances (but I was not tried very hard and I am not a specialist in this subject). Nevertheless, I asked four powerful specialists in graph theory, but without any advances too. So I think that you may repost your question at MathOverflow.

Comment: If you're interested, we've made some progress toward it in our university with some Graph theory specialists, using among others the probabilistic method and ramanujan graphs. we found that for graphs with degree $\sim d$ to have girth of roughly d (which proves $O(d)$ edges in small vertex sets) they need to have $\Theta(d^d)$ vertices rather than $d^2$. 

Glad to see that anyone actually finds this interesting :)